# Scheduling many cron jobs to run every 5 min but not in the same time

Tags: linux, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm using cron to run many processes every 5 min.
It looks like this:

```
*/5       *       *       *       *       execute task1
*/5       *       *       *       *       execute task2
*/5       *       *       *       *       execute task3
*/5       *       *       *       *       execute task4
*/5       *       *       *       *       execute task5
*/5       *       *       *       *       execute task6
```

and so forth....

This cause all take to run in the same time.
Is there away I can make sure all will be spread within the 5 min time spread?
Meaning, let say its now 0:00 so: task1 will run at 0:00 and task2 at 0:01, task3 at 0:02 and task7 will also run at 0:00 (like take1).

Or any other way I can spread out the tasks with in the 5 min time.

Answer (score 0):

How about 0/5 or 1/5 or 2/5 etc in the minute field? Meaning every five minutes staring at 0, 1 or 2

Comment: You mean like this?:
0/5       *       *       *       *       execute task1 |
1/5       *       *       *       *       execute task2 |
2/5       *       *       *       *       execute task3 |
3/5       *       *       *       *       execute task4 |
4/5       *       *       *       *       execute task5 |
5/5       *       *       *       *       execute task6 |

Comment: This is scheduling to run once every hour.

I found that I need to replace the */5 with the list of the minutes in an hour. So, if I want to run if from :01 and then in :06 and so on I need to replace it with 1,6,11,16,21,26,31,36,41,46,51,56 in the minutes column